# Help!!! How do I add text to a contact form?

Tags: php, forms

I have a total rookie questions. I don't start my php classes for a few weeks and need to get this done by today, if possible. I included the code I got off the ftp, as well as the image of the page. I did not attach my attempt at this! Also, when I was trying to do this, nothing would show. I flushed the cache as instructed, but still nothing, so if you have suggestions I would love to hear them.

THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU, if you can help me with this. Looks as if this code is getting messed up, is there a way to attach a file that isn't an image? If is also here: http://www.turnkeylinux.org/files/attachments/php%20help.txt

The text I need added in RED and CENTERED in the left column is below and I also need the email address to be a link:

ATTENTION RETURNING CUSTOMERS
This is our exciting new WEBSITE!
We are glad to have you back.
Because of the transition, we were not able to save your password information.
To reset your password, you will need to click on the Forgot Your Password option.
This will send you an email and you can then reset your password.
All credit card information and order history was deleted.
If you would like your previous order history, please email info@theh2oguru.com
Please place: “Need Prior Purchase History” in the subject line.

Code of current page.

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
```

and

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer login form template
 *
 * @see app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/login.phtml
 */
/** @var $this Mage_Customer_Block_Form_Login */
?>
<div class="account-login">

    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getPostActionUrl() ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
        <div class="col2-set ">
            <div class="new-users">

                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Customers') ?></h2>

            </div>
        <div class="col-1 new-users">
        <p><?php echo $this->__('By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more. <p> ') ?></p>

                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?>" class="button" onclick="window.location='<?php echo Mage::helper('persistent')->getCreateAccountUrl($this->getCreateAccountUrl()) ?>';"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Create an Account') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="col2-set shipping_tax">
<div class=" registered-users">

                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Registered Customers') ?></h2>
                            <div class="col-1">
                    <p><?php echo $this->__('If you have an account with us, please log in.') ?></p>
                    <ul class="form-list">
                        <li>
                            <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="text" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="pass" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
                    <!--<p class="required"><?php //echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>-->

        <div class="col-2 registered-users">
                <div class="buttons-set">
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->getForgotPasswordUrl() ?>" class="f-left"><?php echo $this->__('Forgot Your Password?') ?></a>
                    <button type="submit" class="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                </div>
                </div>

             </div>

            </div>


        </div>
        <?php if (Mage::helper('checkout')->isContextCheckout()): ?>
            <input name="context" type="hidden" value="checkout" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var dataForm = new VarienForm('login-form', true);
    //]]>
    </script>
</div>
```

This image is just to represent the placement of the text, we are not actually using the universal password in this, but the text above.

[image]

Comment: You should never ever do this (change the password for all customers and tell the whole world about the new password). A victim simply has to guess a valid mail address and can then login to your shop in the name of another customer.

Comment: You are correct, Simon. We are using the text in the post and not in the picture. This is simply to represent the placement (below the button). Good catch on your part though. Thanks! Beth

Answer (score 4):

Copy the login.phtml file under /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/ and place it under var/www/html/app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/persistent/customer/form/. Add the code below to login.phtml.Also below I added image showing how it effected my login page.

```
<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="color: #ff0000;">ATTENTION RETURNING CUSTOMERS This is our exciting new WEBSITE! We are glad to have you back. Because of the transition, we were not able to save your password information. To reset your password, you will need to click on the Forgot Your Password option. This will send you an email and you can then reset your password. All credit card information and order history was deleted. If you would like your previous order history, please email info@theh2oguru.com</span><br /><span style="color: #ff0000;"> Please place: &ldquo;Need Prior Purchase History&rdquo; in the subject line.</span></p>
```

add it under:

```
 <div class="new-users">

                <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Customers') ?></h2>

        </div>
    <div class="col-1 new-users">
    <p><?php echo $this->__('By creating an account with our store, you will be able to move through the checkout process faster, store multiple shipping addresses, view and track your orders in your account and more. <p> ') ?></p>
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly for adding the content to my login page. I added some breaks in the content and posted. I appreciate your help and speed.  How do I give you a good rating?

Comment: You just have to accept my answer by clicking the check mark by my answer.

Comment: But please make sure to copy the template to your theme! Do not modify it under `base/default`! @StevenLynn, maybe you can edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @simon great point! Will do!